# Create a new array with common string in all arrays in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

Lets say we have below array

```
arrays=[["a","b", "c"],["b","g","c"],["b","c","g"]]
```

To find common array fields we can do `arrays[0] & arrays[1] & arrays[2]` which will return `["b","c"]` in this case.  This works fine. But how can we do the same when the array count is not predictable?

My initial thought is doing something like a loop like this.

```
array_count.times do |index|
 #but this way how can I achieve same above or any better approach???
end
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What do you mean by dynamically?

Comment: @mbuechmann Just meant the array count is not static. so need looping

Comment: Why are you mentioning `arrays[3]`?

Comment: Your result cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @sawa Thank you for reporting. It was a mistake and haven't noticed when I wrote the question as I put that just to provide a basic idea on the requirement. fixed it now though..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Reduce method

```
result=arrays.reduce do |x,y|
  x & y
end

p result
```

output

```
["b", "c"]
```

Update

Another short way would be

```
 arrays.reduce(:&)
```

Comment: Or `arrays.reduce(:&)`.

Comment: @mu is too short ah okay, updated your short solution.

Comment: I have a general suggestion. If someone leaves a comment that contains what you regard as an improvement on your answer, don't just include it as an addendum to your question, but instead rewrite your answer. Here  you might begin with @muistooshort's suggestion and possibly then--for the benefit of those new to Ruby--explain what that means when used with a block instead. You can then thank the commenter in a comment, saying you have altered your answer in light of the suggestion. After all, the whole idea is to make answers as educational as possible.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland sure , I will do henceforth.